# I want to get all the names on table A that are referencing table B

Tags: php, mysql, database

In laravel i could do this by assuming that there is a relationship between the two tables child and parent.

I could access how many times is parent using the child.

$child->parent->id;

but in pure PHP i have no idea how that works. So far i`ve only tried this

```
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
foreach ($shopAssistants as $shopAS) {
if($shopAS['shop_id'] != $shop['id']){
?> 
<option id = "<?php echo $shop['id']; ?>"><?php echo $shop['shop_name']; ?> 
</option>
}
```

Comment: this is not a job for `PHP`, but a simple `SQL` query.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Can you please tell me how to build that query?

Comment: simple `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Assuming that by 'table', you mean the kind of table that you find in a relational database, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @bleard this is difficult to tell, without having ever seen the the table definition. one simply cannot run a query or join tables without knowing against which data structure the query runs. the `if` condition `$shopAS['shop_id'] != $shop['id']` makes me wonder; these seem to be shop-assistants, which are not at a shop... there would at least need to be an `else` branch, with `option` attribute `selected`, else the topmost `option` will appear to be "selected", despite it isn't... and the actual `selected` value would be missing from the `select` `option`s.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i solved the problem by a simple query i just was confused because i never worked directly on PHP. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Collapse one of the arrays

```
 $shopIds  = array_column($shops, 'id');

 foreach ($shopAssistants as $shopAS) {
      if(in_array($shopAS['shop_id'],$shopIds){
 ?> 
 <option id = "<?php echo $shop['id']; ?>"><?php echo $shop['shop_name']; ?> 
 </option>
 }
```

Array column will return just a single column from a multi-dimensional array.  So if you have

```
$shops = [ 
   ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo'],
   ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'foo'],
   ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'foo'],
]
```

With `array_column($shops, 'id')` and given the example above, I would expect this as the result

```
[1,2,3]
```

By reducing the data down like this, you can just use `in_array` which saves you from having to do 2 loops.

**-Note-**

If shops is an object, you can probably just cast it to an array like so:

```
$shopIds  = array_column((array)$shops, 'id');
```

Assuming the property `id` is public.

Comment: upvoted, because it is not necessarily wrong. there's just an `else` branch missing.